# Изменение Gauge через Windows API (PostMessage)

Tags: winapi, windows, delphi, потоки-данных, асинхронность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, наименование WM сообщения, через которое можно обратиться к компоненту “Gauge” (чтоб менять свойство «Progress», используя PostMessage), управлять Gauge я буду из потока.

Вот, например, на одном из сайтов нашел похожую рабочую штуку, но не знаю, насколько эта реализация правильная:

Модуль, в котором выполняется поток:

```
  const
   MY_MESS = WM_USER + 100;

 procedure ThProcFile.Execute;
 var  
   LCount: integer;  
 begin  
 …
 while PrCount - LCount >= BlockSize do
     begin
       PrSourseStream.Read(LBuffer, BlockSize);
       EncipherBlock(LBuffer);
       PrDestStream.Write(LBuffer, BlockSize);
       Inc(LCount, BlockSize);
        PostMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle, MY_MESS, 1, LCount);
 …
     end;
 end;
```

Модуль основного окна:

```
 public
     procedure MyProgress(var msg: TMessage); message MY_MESS;
   end;
 ….
 procedure TFMain.MyProgress(var msg: TMessage);
 begin
   Gauge1.Progress := msg.LParam;
 end;
```

Спасибо.

P.S. "Synchronize" - тормозит поток в 2 раза.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы собираетесь как-то взаимодействовать с формами из потока (менять свойства, выводить текст и т.д.), то без `Syncronize` никак. Если это тормозит работу потока, сделайте вывод прогресса не в каждой итерации.

Если вы будете отправлять WM сообщения форме из потока, то `Syncronize` не нужен. Чтобы поток не ожидал окончания обработки отправленного сообщения, делайте `PostMessage` вместо `SendMessage`.

Comment: Я так и сделал, обратился через "PostMessage" (как я отобразил в примере, см. выше), я такое нашел на одном из форумов, вместо "Syncronize". Говорят тормозов меньше.   
Но в результате, пришел к одной и той же скорости обработки, что и с "PostMessage", то и "Syncronize" (см. выше).    
Поэтому и спрашиваю: может в коде (см.выше) где-то закралась **ошибка**?    
О частоте обращений - я подумаю - спасибо

Comment: @Konstantin78 в коде выше нет никаких потоков. Если это ваша реализация, а не пример, то вы явно что-то не так делаете.

Покажите ваш поток и обработчик сообщения.

Насчет частоты обращений - сообщать из потока о прогрессе чаще 2-4 раз в секунду нет смысла - это будет только "забивать" очередь сообщений большим количеством неактуальных данных.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я поправил мой рабочий пример.
Насчет частоты, тогда нужно ставить компонент TTimer, для соблюдения частоты срабатывания?

Comment: Никаких ошибок, вроде, нет. Если закомментировать строчку с `PostMessage` выполняться будет быстрее?

Для соблюдения частоты таймер не нужен. Прикиньте "на глаз" сколько итераций выполняется в секунду.

    i := 0; // integer
    while PrCount - LCount >= BlockSize do
    begin
      if i = 0 then
        PostMessage(Application.MainForm.Handle, MY_MESS, 1, LCount);
      inc(i);
      i := i mod 42; // i будет обнуляться каждую 42-ю итерацию
    end;

Подберите вместо числа 42 такое число, при котором прогресс будет обновляться пару раз в секунду.

Comment: Честно говоря, если убрать все "Synchronize" и "PostMessage", а просто с потока обновлять Gauge, то все делается в 2 раза быстрее.   
Но так неправильно.

Да с "mod" - легче пошло

Comment: @Konstantin78 "просто с потока обновлять Gauge" может плохо кончится (словите AV, например).